# Ethernet won't work after reboot, Says my network is unclaimed

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I've tried a bunch of stuff already looking through many forums but alot of the stuff requires me to have internet connection. I don't have one sadly. I do `sudo lshw -c network` and all it just says my network is unclaimed. I cannot sudo update or apt get anything because of no internet connection. Any help please? How do I claim my network? I do have some usb keys and another laptop connected to the internet tho. So that is at my disposal. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu updates are performed by downloading software packages from servers that are located on the Internet.  Without an Internet connection commands like update and apt will fail because your device cannot connect to the servers hosting that software.

There is no reasonable work-around to this reality other than connecting the target Ubuntu device to the Internet via WiFi or some other means.